# Unable tp read zipfile using Apache Tika

Tags: java, zip, apache-tika

i am using Apache Tika 1.5 for parsing the contents present in a zip file,

here's my sample code

```
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    context.set(Parser.class, parser);
    ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = TikaInputStream.get(new File(zipFilePath));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);

        logger.info("Content:\t" + handler.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

in the logger statement all i see is org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler@5bd8e367

i am missing something, unable to figure it out,
looking for some help

Comment: Did you make sure you included both Tika Core and Tika Parser jars on your classpath, along with their dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you need to make sure you have all the right jars. You can call Apache Tika with only the `tika-core` jar on your classpath, but it won't be able to do that much in the way of parsing. For parsing, you need `tika-core` plus `tika-parsers` plus all of their dependencies. Simplest thing to do for that is to use Maven, it'll handle it for you.

Otherwise, there's one problematic line in your code:

```
ContentHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
```

If you want the plain text of the file, I'd suggest using:

```
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
```

If you want the XHTML version, then you'll instead want something like:

```
ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();
```

Finally, if you want control about how the embedded documents in the zip file get extracted / handled, take a look at the examples on the [Tika Wiki for Recursion](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/RecursiveMetadata)

Comment: thanks @Gagravarr all the dependencies are maintained and upto date in pom.xml. the problem is with DefaultHandler, it pretty much does nothing, after changing it to ToXMLContentHandler issues was resolved,
thanks to the tika user mailing list where i got the quick help about the handler and RecursiveMetadataParser Usage